# In python how __name__ resolves to __main__ by default?

Tags: python, namespaces

In python how does `__name__` is set to `__main__` by default. 
when we say print `__name__` it outputs `__main__`.

Comment: \_\_name\_\_ is set to \_\_main\_\_

Comment: There are already many answers to this question, for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do